# Java Mutiny Multi from CompletableFuture<List<T>>

Tags: java, reactive, completable-future, mutiny

say you have a method:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> getStuffAsync()
```

I want the same stream as:

```
Multi<Integer> stream  = Multi
.createFrom().completionStage(() -> getStuffAsync())
.onItem().transformToIterable(Function.identity())
```

which is a stream of each integer returned by the list from the method specified at the beggining...

but without the `onItem().transformToIterable()`, hopefully something like:

```
Multi.createFrom().completionStageIterable(() -> getStuffAsync())
```

purely for aesthetic reasons and to save on valuable characters

Comment: What problem does `onItem().transformToIterable()` cause for you? It converts the Multi<List<Integer>> to Multi<Integer> for you.

Comment: I like your username sir, I've downedvoted the answer but upvoted your comment to make it even. Now to the point, there is nothing wrong with `onItem().transformToIterable()` but feels there may be a nicer shorter way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Multi.createFrom().iterable()` and pass in the result of the CompletableFuture.

```
Multi<Integer> stream = Multi
                    .createFrom()
                    .iterable(getStuffAsync().get());
```

---

##### Alternatively use a utility method to create it.

Create this class Multi.java (or other name) in a package such as util:

```
package util;

import io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.*;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.function.Function;


public interface Multi<T> extends io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi<T> {
    static <T> io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi<T> createFromCompletionStageIterable(CompletableFuture<? extends Iterable<T>> completableFuture) {
        return MultiCreate.INSTANCE.completionStage(completableFuture).onItem().transformToIterable(Function.identity());
    }
}
```

Then you can use your custom method like this:

```
Multi<Integer> stream = util.Multi
.createFromCompletionStageIterable(getStuffAsync());
```

Comment: I wished `.get()` method was named `.butNotReally()` so it would paint a more accurate picture of this answer as: `getStuffAsync().butNotReally()`

Comment: Okay, I updated and added a different option so that you dont have to use `getStuffAsync().butNotReally()`